# Trust TB-7300 / Adesso CyberTablet M14 in OSX 10.8

Tags: macos, drivers, osx-mountain-lion, graphics-tablet

My sister have been using a Trust TB-7300 with her Macbook for some time. Note that even though Trust does not provide OSX drivers for this tablet, she's been able to use [drivers provided by Adesso for their CyberTablet M14](http://www.adesso.com/en/section-blog/92-tablet/447-tablet-faq-list.html), since it's the same hardware only differently branded.

[image: http://i.minus.com/jbxXnGTbVfPZCT_xs.jpg]

Unfortunately after updating to OSX 10.8, she is no longer able to use the tablet. The driver seem to not recognize it (tested on her macbook as well as another imac). You can use the pen in 'point-and-click' mode, but dragging it does not result in drawing lines and pressure detection is not working either.

So my question is: does anyone know of a mountain-lion working driver for this tablet? Maybe it is sold by yet another brand, who provides 10.8 compatible software? Or maybe you know of any other way to make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adesso tech support was kind enough to provide me with an updated driver, even though the tablet wasn't branded by them. Here's a link for anyone needing it:
http://www.waltop.com/download/GM-PenPad-V213-2012-0806.zip

And yes, as you can divine from the URL, the tablet was actually manufactured by Waltop, so if you're ever in need for updated drivers, [try their site](http://www.waltop.com/english/01_products/02_detail.php?SID=149)!